# How can I create new book and assign two authors with it using Rails miniTest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, tdd, associations, minitest

Doing TDD

I facing a problem creating a book and assigning two authors with it. There is a failure in the creation. It says that there is an AssociationTypeMismatch: Author(#15100) expected, got nil which is an instance of NilClass(#40. I suppose that the format "authors: []" is not have been read well by something.

This is the test:

```
def test_has_many_and_belongs_to_mapping
 apress = Publisher.find_by(name: 'Apress')
 assert_equal 2, apress.books.size

 book = Book.new(
  title: 'Rails E-Commerce 3nd Edition',
  authors: [
    Author.find_by(first_name: 'Christian', last_name: 'Hellsten'),
    Author.find_by(first_name: 'Jarkko', last_name: 'Laine')
  ],
  published_at: Time.now,
  isbn: '123-123-123-x',
  blurb: 'E-Commerce on Rails',
  page_count: 300,
  price: 30.5
 )

 # apress.books << book

 # apress.reload
 # book.reload

 # assert_equal 3, apress.books.size
 # assert_equal 'Apress', book.publisher.name
end
```

This is the error:

[image]

MY ERD:

[image]

My schema:

[image]

Comment: Its actually a fairly typical nil error. You're using `find_by` which will return nil if a record can't be found and the records you assume exist don't. While you could use `.find_by!` which would warn you with an exception you I can't really see why you're looking up the records by name in the first place. Either just reference the fixture directly (for example `authors(:one)`) or setup instance variables in the test setup.

Comment: The whole test is very confusing though and I don't get what its actually supposed to be testing. If you want to test that a class has a HABTM assocation you can do `assert_equal :has_and_belongs_to_many, Book.reflect_on_association(:authors)&.macro, 'Book should have and belong to many authors'`. Actually setting up and assocating the items will most likely be covered later by integration tests.

Comment: Another thing here is that you're going to be very dissapointed if you expect the timestamp columns to actually contain timestamps or be useful in anyway - HABTM doesn't have a join model that will actually fill the timestamps. Instead HABTM is just a "dumb" table with two foreign keys that can only be used indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is a meaningful `setup` of data needed before this test runs. Even though those publishers and books may exist in your development environment/database, the test suite usually is configured to wipe the database clean between runs.

If you have fixtures defined, then you can reference them like this:

**test/fixtures/publishers.yml**

```yaml
apress:
  id: 1
  name: Apress
```

**test/fixtures/authors.yml**

```yaml
hellsten:
  id: 1
  first_name: Christian
  last_name: Hellsten

laine:
  id: 2
  first_name: Jarkko
  last_name: Laine
```

**test/fixtures/books.yml**

```yaml
beginning_ruby:
  title: Beginning Ruby
  publisher_id: 1

ruby_recipes:
  title: Ruby Recipes
  publisher_id: 1
```

So that the test would look more like this:

```rb
def test_has_many_and_belongs_to_mapping
 apress = publishers(:apress)
 assert_equal 2, apress.books.size

 book = Book.new(
  title: 'Rails E-Commerce 3nd Edition',
  authors: [
    Author.find_by(first_name: 'Christian', last_name: 'Hellsten'),
    Author.find_by(first_name: 'Jarkko', last_name: 'Laine')
  ],
  published_at: Time.now,
  isbn: '123-123-123-x',
  blurb: 'E-Commerce on Rails',
  page_count: 300,
  price: 30.5
 )

 apress.books << book

 apress.reload
 book.reload

 assert_equal 3, apress.books.size
 assert_equal 'Apress', book.publisher.name
end
```

Or instead of using fixtures, you could create the content before the test:

So that the test would look more like this:

```rb
setup do
  publisher = Publisher.create!(name: 'Apress')
  publisher.books.create!(title: 'Beginning Ruby')
  publisher.books.create!(title: 'Ruby Recipes')
  Author.create!(first_name: 'Christian', last_name: 'Hellsten')
  Author.create!(first_name: 'Jarkko', last_name: 'Laine')
end

def test_has_many_and_belongs_to_mapping
 apress = Publisher.find_by(name: 'Apress')
 assert_equal 2, apress.books.size

 book = Book.new(
  title: 'Rails E-Commerce 3nd Edition',
  authors: [
    Author.find_by(first_name: 'Christian', last_name: 'Hellsten'),
    Author.find_by(first_name: 'Jarkko', last_name: 'Laine')
  ],
  published_at: Time.now,
  isbn: '123-123-123-x',
  blurb: 'E-Commerce on Rails',
  page_count: 300,
  price: 30.5
 )

 apress.books << book

 apress.reload
 book.reload

 assert_equal 3, apress.books.size
 assert_equal 'Apress', book.publisher.name
end
```

That way your database has those values, and your `find_by()` calls should return data, and not `nil`.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you for the answer that helps to tackle the problem too. 

A person in a Rails community helps me understand the problem too and he advised me to use `find_by_or_create_by` that tackle the problem so well. Your answer can tackle the problem so well too. 